# Custom dimensions not tracked in Google Analytics HTTP requests (Measurement Protocol)

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api, universal-analytics, measurement-protocol

When using analytics.js, I can successfully track events including custom dimensions this way (as described [in the docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets)):

```
ga('send', 'event', 'category', 'action', {
    'metric18': 8000,
    'dimension6': 'crocodile'
});
```

However, when using the Measurement Protocol (ie. HTTP requests), I can't seem to find the way of including custom dimensions and metrics to the event tracking, as I haven't found any reference in the documentation.

This is what I've tried so far (based on the examples found in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide#event)). In both cases, the event has actually been tracked, but without any custom dimensions or metrics associated.

```
http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?
 v=1             // Version.
 &tid=UA-XXXX-Y  // Tracking ID / Property ID.
 &cid=555        // Anonymous Client ID.

 &t=event        // Event hit type
 &ec=video       // Event Category. Required.
 &ea=play        // Event Action. Required.
 &metric18=8000
 &dimension6=crocodile
```

and

```
http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?
 v=1             // Version.
 &tid=UA-XXXX-Y  // Tracking ID / Property ID.
 &cid=555        // Anonymous Client ID.

 &t=event        // Event hit type
 &ec=video       // Event Category. Required.
 &ea=play        // Event Action. Required.
 &el={"metric18":8000,"dimension6":"crocodile"}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on the [collection devguide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#customs) you are using the wrong parameter names, please try:

```
http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?
 v=1             // Version.
 &tid=UA-XXXX-Y  // Tracking ID / Property ID.
 &cid=555        // Anonymous Client ID.

 &t=event        // Event hit type
 &ec=video       // Event Category. Required.
 &ea=play        // Event Action. Required.
 &cm18=8000
 &cd6=crocodile
```

(The part of the devguide you were looking at is for the web tracking JS instead of collection.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although I was indeed looking at the Measurement Protocol documentation, but wrong section (Dev Guide instead of Parameter Reference)

Comment: @XeviPujol I guess I didn't write that clearly since they are both subsections of collection. But the link with 'collection/analyticsjs' is from the wrong subsection for measurement; you can really only trust the 'collection/protocol' section for specifics. At any rate, glad it solves the problem!